# Why is this question closed as tools recommendation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103280) question about difference between implode and explode closed as reason 'recommend ...', IMHO it belongs to help vampire questions, but I don't think it is asking to recommending anything. Even the usage of implode or explode is simple and can be found easily, can we assume it is equivalent to tutorial recommendation? (Ok, I'm not saying 'no' to this question, just have some confusion want to clarify :) )

I'm just doubt the current closing reason, not saying it is a good, or even valid question, so I don't flag to reopen directly...

I just found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914008) about difference between implode and join, but this question is quite well received. Why do 2 questions have so different fate?

Comment: Presumably because the former was more recent and could be explained by someone just looking at the language's documentation (and there's more active close-voters these days). The other is 3 years old and probably escaped being closed mostly for that reason... (wouldn't hurt if it was closed though...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question feels like it is asking for an off-site resource, aka documentation or a tutorial on the subject.

I could have close voted as too broad or unclear as well.

What the OP should have done is explain what they don't understand. In its current state it could also be that they don't understand English. Answerers have to either make a guess or assume zero-knowledge of the OP. Also for future visitors the question and answers are probably useless because they can't verify if their issue is similar to that of the OP.

The second question you linked to is actually asking for advantage for one over the other method. That is a better question and can be answered by showing its differences.

Still ... PHP ...