# Why was this question marked as recommending a resource?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, close-reasons

I ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168392/how-do-i-insert-spaces-between-each-character-in-a-string) question the other day. Although it was almost certainly a duplicate, I couldn't find its match and moved on.

Today I saw that it was marked as off-topic. Good. However, the reason was stated to be "Recommending a resource". This seems like the wrong reason as nowhere does the question ask for any resources.

Am I missing some unspoken additional use of this reason? I.e., the I-know-its-a-duplicate-but-can't-find-it reason or the yeah-this-question-is-bad-but-none-of-the-other-reasons-fit reason?

Possibly related to [Why was this question put on-hold as "asking for off-site resources"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337670/why-was-this-question-put-on-hold-as-asking-for-off-site-resources)

The answer put there was essentially: "Yup, that's the wrong reason but we all agree it was bad so lets just ignore it."

Comment: *how to read.table in r this text file which numbers are without space? I want there was space between numbers.* Somebody get the garlic.

Comment: The tool recommendation close reason gets regularly used to mean *"I reckon that somewhere in the world there's probably a tool that could in some way be used to help solve your specific problem, therefore you shouldn't be allowed to ask how to solve your specific problem at all."* This is a really dumb way to apply the close reason, but my [previous attempt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215135/200582) to persuade the community to stop using the close reason this way met only a mixed response.

Comment: There's also this idea I've seen on Meta a few times that a question that's asks for someone to write all the code for them is the same as asking for an off-site tutorial. I can't find the question where I argued against this but it gets mentioned here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332775/voting-to-close-as-recommendation-when-no-recommendation-has-been-asked-for and here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323844/why-is-this-question-closed-as-tools-recommendation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [original version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41168392/1) is a lot different than the current one, and could be interpreted as 'please recommend me a library to import a data file', though I'd choose 'Too broad' myself. Note that the notice specifies that *only two* close-voters chose this specific close reason; the rest chose other reasons, maybe *after* the question got its current form.

In the case that multiple close reasons were voted for, the system will take the most frequent one. (In case of a tie, the [last close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39664/295232) (among the tied ones) will be chosen by the system.)

Comment: Ok, Makes sense. Just a quick follow up: If you saw this question in its current form but couldn't find its duplicate, how would you deal with it? Just move on? I run into this problem a lot.

Comment: All fair points, but even with the original version of the question, it seems like a major stretch to interpret it as a "recommendation" question. It's just another one of the many low-quality crap questions we get. I usually pick "too broad" or "lacks MCVE" as close reasons for these. Neither are perfect, but the good reasons have been proactively taken away from us.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, both 'lacks minimal understanding' and 'too localized' are better fits for this question that any of the current reasons.

Comment: @code11: If you cannot a find a good close reason, you should not vote to close indeed. You can still downvote though.

Comment: @MatthieuM if you cannot find a good close reason, you can always use a *custom one*. Just don't use 'because it's a bad question'.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Would "I know for sure there is a duplicate of this but can't find it" a reasonable custom flag? I mean its asking about string splitting! I'm pretty sure there's something about that already. Again, not super important for this question, just for a heuristic.

Comment: @code11 I'd just put that as a comment, maybe somebody else can find it for you. A comment like that doesn't help the OP solving his/her issue and/or improving the post, so it's not suitable as a close reason.

Comment: Definitely not useful as a custom flag, @code. Moderators process those manually, so what would you expect them to do? Go through and look for the dupe themselves, the one you couldn't find? (They won't do this, they'll just decline your flag.) Like Glorfindel says, you *might* consider leaving this as a comment, in case someone who is more familiar with the questions on that tag comes along, and your comment is able to jog their memory. But do try to provide more information in that comment, too, otherwise it runs the risk of just being noise.

Comment: @CodyGray custom *close reason*, not custom *moderator flag*.

Comment: @code11 If the close voter who *knows* it's a duplicate cannot find the link, how do you expect the asker to have found it? Duplicate questions aren't necessarily bad or an indication that the asker hasn't done enough research. Closing them as duplicates provides the askers with the answers they need. Closing them for other reasons does not. Admittedly there are a lot of low-quality duplicate questions. They are bad because they are low quality, not because they are duplicates, and may be closed for other reasons if they fit.

Comment: I often feel uncomfortable when I see a post is closed as tools recommending even it doesn't contain any terms, pharses or words request to do so.in terms of using close votes, quality is more important than quantity, right?