# Why was this question closed as "requesting an offsite resource"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

I'm asking why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969753/how-to-find-multiple-element-that-are-the-same-in-a-list-in-java) was closed.

Picture of the post in case it gets re-deleted:

[image]

The close reason is:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

But I don't see any request for any off-site resource. The OP simply wants to know how to get the indexes for duplicate elements.

Maybe the question was closed for other reasons? The question doesn't include an attempt at the problem, and isn't particularly well-written or insightful, which could contribute to it being viewed as low-quality. However, this doesn't seem to fit as 4 of the 5 reviewers chose the 'off-site' reason.

Any ideas? Should it be reopened?

**Edit:**

It has been reopened and reclosed as "too broad". I'm not sure I agree with that either, as there are plenty of questions that ask, "How do I do {simple task}?" that aren't closed as such.

Furthermore, I think I have a better solution. After looking around a bit more extensively, I found [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095090/index-of-duplicates-items-in-java-arraylist). We should close this question as a duplicate. Of course the original can then be closed as "too broad" if wanted.

---

<sup>For those wondering why my answer seems to mirror the top, older answer, it is because that answer originally used a different (wrong) method. When I pointed out the flaw, his answer became pretty much the same as mine. (And attracted some upvotes for being older I suppose.)</sup>

Comment: This is the kind of situation where you'd think "hmm, were the reviewers given an audit with text from a completely different question that *is* a request for off-site resources?", but no, it's not an audit. So I got nothing.

Comment: (Who wants to bet that at least one of them voted to close the question based on the appearance of the string "is there any"? That's the only remotely plausible reason I can think of for someone choosing that reason. Otherwise... yeah I got nothing.)

Comment: So strange that noone ever tried to iterate through list in Java so far... Probably pretty new language :)... I can see why one can vote (last) as "where to find guide on iterating through the list" and the rest - unclear, too broad, missing MCVE,...

Comment: I think @BoltClock is right about keyword "is there any". I observe this quite a lot, for example if C# question contains "NullReferenceException" keyword  - almost immediately people start casting close votes for famous duplicate question about that exception, without even reading the question.

Comment: Reclosed as too broad, most likely because it comes out as a write-me-a-code request. I would have preferred unclear (I think it's asking us to find a duplicate in an array if there is one, but I'm not 100% sure), but still better than offsite-request.

Comment: "Is there any" may be understood as a request to browse the documentation for the OP to find the class/functionthat satisfies OP's needs. In this sense it is an analogy to "is there a book" on a more detailed level - "is there a function". Or a simpler interpretation - that fact that OP is asking such a question suggest that they don't know references exist, so it must be that *de facto* they are asking to find the official reference for them and point to the solution :)

Comment: @BartoszKP clever. Are you willing to post this as an answer and subject yourself to community voting, though? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Perhaps I could, but my comment is pure speculation. A better source of information is someone who actually voted this way :)

Comment: Some people hate reasonable questions. Some people just want to see the world burn... they may be the same people.

Comment: @TinyGiant The question might be reasonable but is not a good SO question. Your description of the voters seems a bit ... over the top :0

Comment: @BartoszKP Let me get this straight. It is a perfectly on-topic reasonable question... yet it is not a good SO question... WAT? If it hasn't been asked before, that's great. Another Q&A to add to the repository. If it has been asked before, close it as a duplicate. Why should it be closed simply because it's an easy question?

Comment: @TinyGiant Let me get this straight. The guidelines on how does a good question look like are easy to find in the [help]. And they are not the same as you seem to suggest. There are many reasonable questions, i.e. "In what year did Turing publish his famous paper?" - but reasonable doesn't imply a good fit for SO. The discussed question is grey area at best (and only thanks to the edits).

Comment: just because others post off-topic low quality crap and did not get the corrective attention it deserves does not mean that any subsequent low quality off-topic crap should get a pass

Comment: I'm not one of the close voters but my interpretation of that close reason encompasses questions where OP seems to be asking for a tutorial of some kind.

Comment: How is that even remotely off-topic? It is asking how to find the duplicates in a list (with the requirement of getting the indices of each duplicate). It's a duplicate for sure, but there is no way that is off-topic. It is a practical, answerable programming problem that is unique to software development @BartoszKP

Comment: @TinyGiant As I've said - it's grey area, because even if it is a programming problem - it is definitely too broad. It asks "Is there any way", and in general there are many (to be precise: infinite) possible answers, because there are **multiple** (to be precise: infinite) ways to achieve what the OP asks.

Comment: SO's doing the Wikipedia thing now. Instead of "all valid topics for an encyclopedia entry", they went for "all topics that will make us as hoity-toity as Britannica". In SO's case, it's just "all questions that will make the site look clever despite its best use case being for people who are less clever than they'd like getting answers to unclear problems with unclever solutions. It'll end up some monument to the interview whiteboard phenomenon.

Comment: @BartoszKP There are many ways to solve any programming problem. Should any question that has more than one possible answer be closed as too broad?

Comment: @TinyGiant Nice strawman attempt. Currently the consensus seems to be that a question containing a code sample with explanation what doesn't work in this particular piece of code is specific enough.

Comment: @BartoszKP I would love to see that consensus. That seems highly arbitrary and possibly just your personal opinion.

Comment: @TinyGiant For example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @BartoszKP That's a checklist of what a great question contains. That is not in any way a checklist of what is required for a question to be on-topic. A better example would be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281

Comment: @TinyGiant No, it's not - why would you manipulate like that? The post says explicitly - a "good question", not a "great question". On the other hand, your link isn't a very nice example for someone who just said "possibly just your personal opinion". And arguing that because some questions aren't closed implies that they are "good questions" is a classical petitio principii.

Comment: "xxx can be understood as..." would you understand all questions about "How to I do xxx?" as finding tutorial? If not, what is your criteria to understand a question as finding tutorials if it is not requesting tutorials in words directly?

Comment: *"4 of the 5 reviewers chose the 'off-site' reason"* - wait, how can you know this? I thought that all we could conclude with certainty was that it was the (possibly randomly-selected tie-breaking) majority reason - i.e. that at least 1 close voter picked it. Aren't the precise close reasons picked by individual voters private once the question has been closed?

Comment: @MarkAmery close banners say "closed off topic by [close voters]". Then there's a section that says "The users who voted to close gave this specific reason" and has the reason. *After this*, a dash is shown and names are given, *these names are a subset of the close voters*. I always assumed these were the people who voted in accord with the specific reason quoted. Not sure if I'm right or not. (Here's an example with only 4 of the 5 closers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905427/creating-a-toolbox-program-java)

Comment: @River oh, wow. I never bothered reading (or really noticed, to be honest) the second list of close voters. You are almost certainly right, and I am living proof of Joel Spolsky's UI maxim that [users can’t read anything, and if they could, they wouldn’t want to](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/26/designing-for-people-who-have-better-things-to-do-with-their-lives/).

Comment: @MarkAmery while looking at examples to show you, I noticed this is only displayed for "off topic" closures. Bit odd, but I can totally understand you not reading it before.

Comment: I strongly suspect [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323845/4076315) applies here as I've seen the same logic in comments on similar questions: A user asking for something to be written from scratch is asking for a tutorial, therefore they are asking for an off-site resource (because we don't do tutorials). I don't personally agree with this (neither did rene in that answer) but I've seen a few users say it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the close reason was incorrect.

The question has been reopened and reclosed twice, the first time as "too broad", which didn't seem quite right, and the second time as a duplicate. This final closing seems to have taken.

**Edit:**

Or not, the entire post has now been deleted.

**Edit 2:**

It has been undeleted.

**Edit 3:**

It has once again been deleted.

Comment: 3, 20K+ users, voted to delete the question.  As no new information was added that looks OK.

Comment: Yea, I'm a little disappointed due to the rep loss to me and my feeling that the duplicate close was sufficient. On the other hand though, I can't really argue with the decision to close, nor do I feel the question deserves to be undeleted.

Comment: Don't feel disappointed to this, the responsibility of losing reputations is not on the one who discovers the bad questions, but on the one who asks that, right?

Answer (score -5):

Requesting an off-site resource would probably be the incorrect close reason indeed. However, it doesn't matter all that much. The important thing is that the question was closed.

As a rule of thumb: if a question should be closed but was closed for the wrong reason, leave it be. Don't bother re-opening questions just to close them for another reason. Doing so just creates extra work for everyone, by shovelling crap between various review queues.

Looking at the original question https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43969753/1, it is a very broad question that just (not too clearly) asks how to search through a container with no specifics mentioned and no code or effort by the OP. Mostly it is a code begging/"read the manual for me" question.

This could have been closed as too broad, but any form of close reason is fine, since SO is not a code-writing service.

- For reasons unknown, the post was then re-opened by someone who should know better.
- After which it was again closed, this time correctly as too broad.
- The edits did not change the fact that the question is still code begging/"read the manual for me". There is no reason to polish crap, just close it.
- For reasons unknown, the post was then yet again re-opened.
- And now someone has found a duplicate and closed it again, which should finally settle the issue.

Comment: It was reopened for good reasons as the closing reason was not correct. The person knew it better. Closing it for the wrong reasons is not a good practice regardless if the question should be closed or not.

Comment: I think your "rule of thumb" is especially wrong in the case where the difference in close reasons is between "normal closure" and "duplicate closure" as it was here.

Comment: @kaba713 Did you have any arguments? "No I don't agree" is not an argument.

Comment: @River The rule of thumb refers to over-zealous moderators who insist on opening up crap posts just to close them for another reason. In addition to creating additional, mostly pointless review work for everyone, this confuses the OP and everyone who reads the post - is the question ok or not ok?

Comment: @Lundin: What do you mean by did I have any arguments? What kind of argument is it to close a question by a random reason just because it should be closed?

Comment: Agreed that reopening and reclosing creates extra work which is a burden. But... it also rights a wrong which will no longer serve as a source of confusion, and ho boy is there a lot of confusion about closure reasons. Stack Overflow values correct and on-topic information, I don't think that this should stop at the content and should apply to all aspects which includes closure reasons.